# Python FileNotFoundError [Errno 2]

Tags: python, read-data, filenotfounderror

I am newbie to python coding and need your expertise help in my below issue,
Currently I am trying to read data from a txt file and process further once its moved to a list.

Below is my code:

```
case 'add':
            todo = input("enter a todo")+"\n"
            file = open('data.txt','r')
            todos =file.readlines()
            file.close()
            todos.append(todo)
            file = open('data.txt','w')
            file.writelines(todos)
            file.close()
```

Error I'm getting (please note both my main.py and data.txt are in the same folder)

```
 file = open('data.txt','r')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.txt'
```

Comment: "please note both my main.py and data.txt are in the same folder" - please see the linked duplicate, in order to understand why this is *not the important part*. A different rule is used to locate the file.

Comment: Concerning the duplicate: I would advise against using `os.chdir`. The method with `pathlib` is much more flexible and less error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

You should include the full path to where `data.txt` is located if it's not in the same folder; 
Example

```
open("D:\Text\data.txt","w+")
```